# What is the complement of A={1\n:n∈ℕ}

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I derived $(-\infty, 0] \cup \bigcup_{n \in N}(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}) \cup (1, \infty)$. I want to verify this so I can reason about whether the sets are closed, open, or neither. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, this may not be helpful but is it meant to be $(1,-\infty)$?

Comment: You're right. I went ahead and fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me, yeah. For every number $x\in \mathbb R\setminus A$, you have:

- If $x>1$, then every $x$ is OK.
- If $x\leq 0$, then every $x$ is OK.
- If $x\in (0,1)$, there exists some $n$ such that $\frac1n<x$. Taking the smallest such $n>1$ ensures that $\frac 1n<x\leq \frac{1}{n-1}$, meaning that if $x\notin A$, then $x\in (\frac1n,\frac{1}{n-1})$ which proves $x$ is in $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)$

which is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You got an answer from 5xum. But to see whether $A$ is open, closed or neither, you can argue as follows:

If $ \epsilon>0$, the $(1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$ is not a subset of $A$, hence $A$ is not open.

The sequence $(1/n)$ is a convergent sequence in $A$ but the limit $0$ of this squence is not contained in $A$, hence $A$ is not closed.

Comment: I just barely started learning topology, so I'm starting from the basics. I know that open sets are the elements of a topology and that they satisfy a set of axioms. The standard topology of the reals contains any set formed from the arbitrary union of open intervals. Since closed sets are the complements of open sets, I figured that if I could show that the complement of set A wasn't an open interval or the union of several open intervals, then A wasn't closed. I think I'll be covering what you talked about next.

Comment: @LumpyGrads You can do it that way because you can show that $0$ cannot be an element of any open interval that is entirely a subset of the complement of $A$, therefore, the complement of $A$ is not open and $A$ is not closed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.